# RegEx for checking specific rule in string

Tags: regex

I cannot figure out how to make this RegEx syntax work.
https://regex101.com/r/Zcxjtn/1

I would like to check whether a string is valid or not.
Rules:

- The string must consist of 3 capital letters [A-Z]
- If the string is longer than each 3 capital letter blocks must be seperated by a semicolon (;) only
- The string must not start and end with a seperator (;)
- optional: whitespaces are allowed between seperator and next 3-letter sub-string

examples of valid strings:

> AAA;BBB
>
> AAA; BBB
>
> AAA

examples of invalid strings:

> ;AAA
>
> AAA;BBB;
>
> 123;AAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The string must consist of 3 capital letters [A-Z]

- `[A-Z]` matches a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `Z` (index 90) (case sensitive)
- `{3}` matches the previous token exactly 3 times

Put together you get

1. `[A-Z]{3}`

> If the string is longer than each 3 capital letter blocks must be seperated by a semicolon (;) only

Make 1. required in the beginning as `^[A-Z]{3}` followed by another group that occurs 0 or more times until the end of the input `( )*$` containing a leading `;` and 1. from above, so `(;[A-Z]{3})*$`.

Put together you get

2. `^[A-Z]{3}(;[A-Z]{3})*$`

> The string must not start and end with a seperator (;)

Already covered by 2.

> optional: whitespaces are allowed between seperator and next 3-letter sub-string

Add a white-space `\s` that occurs 0 or more times `*`, so `\s*`.

- `\s` matches any whitespace character (equivalent to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Put to the correct location in the regex you get

`^[A-Z]{3}(;\s*[A-Z]{3})*$`

See: https://regex101.com/r/hZ5l6a/1

If you would like to capture only letters, add capture groups `( )` and mark some groups as non-capturing groups `(?: )`

Example:
`^([A-Z]{3})(:?;\s*([A-Z]{3}))*$`

See: https://regex101.com/r/NlDTfq/1